# Dllimport work on visual studio but not in iis server

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, dll

I have a DLL that I have developed. I use this DLL in a website using `DllImport`.

When I run the website via Visual Studio all is okay, but when I run it with the IIS it is stuck with no errors.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [DllImport("D:\\WebApplication1\\WebApplication1\\bin\\dapreporter.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern IntPtr fndapreporter(string inifile, int nReport, int nYear, int nMonth, int nDay, int nType, int nCode, int precision);

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string iniFile = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\bin\WinDAP.ini");
                
                IntPtr pVariant = fndapreporter(iniFile, 0, 2021, 9, 12, 0, 197, 0);

                object sHtml = Marshal.GetObjectForNativeVariant(pVariant);

                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pVariant);
                pVariant = IntPtr.Zero;
                Response.Write(sHtml.ToString());
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) but provide it as text

Comment: If that library tries to do printing, then I am not surprised that it works differently under IIS, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: Make sure your IIS Application Pool is running in 32bit or 64bit to match your .dll.

Comment: Side point `Marshal.Free...` should be in a `finally` block

Comment: Is the dll x64 bit or x32? Might want to force and test your project as x64 bits - don't use default of any cpu

Answer (score 0):

A website's files/folders are relative to the home directory for that particular website. Due to the way `DllImport` works, one can add the desired directory to the `PATH` environment variable and then specify only the filename.

Try the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Hosting;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [DllImport("dapreporter.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern IntPtr fndapreporter(string inifile, int nReport, int nYear, int nMonth, int nDay, int nType, int nCode, int precision);

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IntPtr pVariant = IntPtr.Zero;

            try
            {
                //get path to bin directory
                //string binDir = Server.MapPath("~/bin/");
                string binDir = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/bin/");

                //add bin directory to PATH so DLLImport can find the DLL
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", String.Format("{0};{1}", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH"), binDir));

                string iniFile = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(binDir, "WinDAP.ini"));

                pVariant = fndapreporter(iniFile, 0, 2021, 9, 12, 0, 197, 0);

                object sHtml = Marshal.GetObjectForNativeVariant(pVariant);
                Response.Write(sHtml.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (pVariant != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pVariant);
                    pVariant = IntPtr.Zero;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Resources**:

- [Call function from DLL with non-static path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738555/call-function-from-dll-with-non-static-path)
- [HttpServerUtility.MapPath(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath?view=netframework-4.8)
- [HostingEnvironment.MapPath(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath?view=netframework-4.8)
- [httpcontext.current.server.mappath Object reference not set to an instance of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861368/httpcontext-current-server-mappath-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an/35941701)